# Битрикс. Товары в нескольких разделах и их отображение в каталоге

Tags: битрикс

У меня есть товар - Товар 1, 2, 3, 4 и тд который привязан сразу к нескольким разделам каталога. Элемент каталога отображает эти товары только в самой первой категории, а во всех остальных не отображает. В админке товар отображается верно. В чем может быть проблема? Не достаёт какого - то фильтра для каталога?

Comment: каким компонентом выводите товары? проверьте настройки этого компонента.

Comment: Стандартным компонентом каталога. Почему - то не показывает дублирующие товары в других категориях, только в первой.